# Flexbox: Align between bottom and center?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Does someone know how to create this layout, using flexbox?

[image]

The text is going to be placed in the center, and the button is going to be placed between the text and bottom.

I have this now:

```css
.aligner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="aligner">
  <h3>SUPERMAN</h3>
  <p>FTW</p>
  <button>BUTTON</button>
</div>
```

This aligns everything in the center, but I want only the text to be in center, and the button between center and the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this layout:

- Anonymous element with `flex: 1`
- The title and subtitle (titles)
- Element with `flex: 1` and `display: flex`.

The elements above and below the title will take available space left by titles in equal amounts. So the titles will become centered.

Those elements can also be flex containers, and you can align their contents inside them as desired.

```css
html, body {height: 100% } * { margin: 0; }
.aligner, .below {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.aligner {
  height: 100%;
}
.aligner::before { content: ''; }
.aligner::before, .below {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="aligner">
  <h3>SUPERMAN</h3>
  <p>FTW</p>
  <div class="below">
    <button>BUTTON</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> The text is going to be placed in the center, and the button is going
>   to be placed between the text and bottom.

You can use a combination of [**`auto`** margins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) with an invisible flex item to achieve the layout:

(Edit: I wrote this answer before the question was updated with sample code. So my code is different than in the question. But the method still applies.)

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container > div:nth-child(1) { margin-top: auto; visibility: hidden; }
.container > div:nth-child(2) { margin-top: auto; }
.container > div:nth-child(3) { margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; }

/* non-essential decorative styles */
.container {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.box {
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">BUTTON</div><!-- invisible flex item -->
  <div class="box">SUPERMAN</div>
  <div class="box">BUTTON</div>
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yhfeL0bh/4/)

---

Also, with two minor adjustments, **the bottom item can be flush with the edge**.

```
.container > div:nth-child(1) { /* margin-top: auto; */ visibility: hidden; }
.container > div:nth-child(2) { margin-top: auto; }
.container > div:nth-child(3) { margin-top: auto; /* margin-bottom: auto; */ }
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yhfeL0bh/5/)

OR, just use `justify-content: space-between`:

```
.container > div:nth-child(1) { visibility: hidden; }
/* .container > div:nth-child(2) { margin-top: auto; } */
/* .container > div:nth-child(3) { margin-top: auto;  } */

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: space-between; /* NEW */
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yhfeL0bh/7/)

---

For more alignment options see: [**Methods for Aligning Flex Items**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks man, this also seems like a good approach. I will test it later today!