# Align content of flex items to bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Very simple, a container has to have its children stretched (as they are), but the content of the children divs has to be aligned to the bottom, same as flex-end but while maintaining the height.

Any ideas about how to do that?

Take a look at this pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAjRvo

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background: BurlyWood;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.item{
  flex:1;
  margin: 4px;
  background: Crimson;
}

.item p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <p>ipsum</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <p>dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align an element to bottom with flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000885/align-an-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox)

Comment: The problem with fundamentally changing the question is that it invalidates all existing answers and creates a mess of confusion for people seeking help on this post.

Comment: Consider posting a new question. Also, this may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/33944163/3597276

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the children flex-containers as well.. then align accordingly

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background: BurlyWood;
  display: flex;
}

.item{
  flex:1;
  margin: 4px;
  background: Crimson;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.item p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <p>ipsum</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <p>dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or similarly with flex-columns

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background: BurlyWood;
  display: flex;
}

.item{
  flex:1;
  margin: 4px;
  background: Crimson;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.item p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <p>ipsum</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <p>dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems the best option. But, lets pretend I have more elements in the children div's, for example, and img and a p tag. With this method, both will be aligned to the bottom: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAjRvo

Comment: That would depend on how you want the other elements aligned. If you don't mention other elements we can't account for them. - BUT - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JKNRvN for instance.

Comment: yes, I know that. I tried to make the question simple, but I ended up with a too simple question ;) I have updated the question.

Comment: Please don't change the question that would invalidate existing answers. Ask a new question instead,

Comment: Ok, ill do that. Thanks!

Comment: You should be aware that the new question is likely to have been asked already. Make sure you search carefully first.

Comment: Of course I search first, is faster to find the answer than having to formulate the question and wait for the answer ;)

Comment: Generally though, in flexbox "center and bottom" requires positioning. There is no method within flexbox to do both at the same time - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties/33856609#33856609

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the keyword properties already mentioned, you can also use [***flex auto margins***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276):

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background: BurlyWood;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.item {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 4px;
  background: Crimson;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;             /* NEW */
}
.item p {
  margin: auto 0 0 0;        /* ADJUSTED */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use position absolute for that.

In order to keep the text centered, you need `left` and `right:0`.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background: BurlyWood;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.item{
  flex:1;
  margin: 4px;
  background: Crimson;
  position:relative;
}

.item p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <p>ipsum</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <p>dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You could also use `grow` on one element, so the other will just take space that it requires. This is not a real clean solution in my eyes, but it works:

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background: BurlyWood;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.item{
  flex:1;
  margin: 4px;
  background: Crimson;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item div {
  flex:1;
}

.item p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <p>ipsum</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <p>dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyway to do that without position absolute? Just curious about flex and I thought it could be done "somehow"

Comment: @Chux see update, however the other answer does a better job :)